# Котрибьютинг библиотеки для Django

Tags: python, django, git, github

На `github` имеется библиотека для фреймворка `Django`. Я хочу законтрибьютить ее, но для этого мне нужно включить библиотеку внутрь проекта на `django`, чтобы протестировать изменения, но тогда я не смогу нормально запушить изменения, так как структура папок ломается. Как быть в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Во-первых, создавайте проект отдельно и устанавливайте в его виртуальное окружение библиотеку с помощью команды наподобие `pip install -e путь/к/библиотеке`. Во-вторых, для тестирования нужно не проект руками тыкать, а [писать автоматические тесты](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/)

Comment: Мне нужны исходники библиотеки не в окружении в в самом проекте, чтобы я их правил. Но я не могу  склонировать библиотеку и вносить изменения в нее, так как она требует некоторого взаимодействия с django интерфейсом. А если я склонирую ее в проект, то поломается скруктура папок и я не смогу запушить только нужные изменения

Comment: Ещё раз: устанавливайте свою исправленную библиотеку в проект через pip install. Опция `-e` существует специально для того, чтобы у вас была возможность править библиотеку